# What would be a good expression for "currently widely used and accessible"?

Tags: synonyms, phrase-requests

I am trying to formulate the following sentence:

"-Support for currently widely used and accessible interfaces and devices."

However, I do not want to use "currently widely used and accessible", but I can not find a good alternative.
Do you have any good suggestion?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in:

"X supports **common** interfaces and devices."  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/common)

> - a. Occurring frequently or habitually; usual: It is common for movies    to last 90 minutes or more.
> - b. Most widely known; ordinary:

Answer (score 1):

**Popular** is just fine, or you could go with **ubiquitous**.